# How to Update current selected item after backpress in navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I have successfully implemented navigation drawer but I'm having problems with it.

After selecting fragments and I click the back button, the current fragment pops off and the previous fragment is displayed.

But the title  of the displayed fragment is still that of the previous fragment.

Also,  the item checked in the drawer is still that of the previous fragment.

Please, do you have any idea how I might update the title and checked item?

**My Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    NavigationView navigationView;


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        String about_blog = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/p-about";
        String contri = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/contribute";
        String privy = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/privacy-rules";
        String contact = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/contact_us";
        String advert = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/advertise-here";
        String spons = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/sponsor-us";

        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.menu_home) {
            fragment = new PostFragment();
        }

        if (id == R.id.about_blog) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contri) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_privy) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_advert) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.spons) {
            fragment = new PageFragment();

        } else if (id == R.id.app_about) {
            //fragment = new abtFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.settings) {
            //fragment = new SettingFragment;
        }


        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "Device rotated and onCreate called");

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.menu_home);
        navigationView.getMenu().performIdentifierAction(R.id.menu_home, 0);
    }
```

---

### UPDATE

I have fixed the issue of updating the title of each fragment after each backpress. What I did was to send the title as a string from **MainActivity** to the fragment, then in the fragment I receive it and call:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

**This is how my onNavigationItemSelected Code looks like afterwards**

```
 public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    id = item.getItemId();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String about_blog = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/p-about";
        String contri = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/contribute";
        String privy = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/privacy-rules";
        String contact = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/contact_us";
        String advert = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/advertise-here";
        String spons = "http://example.com/page/json/urls/sponsor-us";

    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.menu_home) {
        fragment = new PostFragment();
        bundle.putString("title", getString(R.string.home));
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    }

    if (id == R.id.about_blog) {
        bundle.putString("title", getString(R.string.about));
        fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contri) {
        bundle.putString("title", getString(R.string.contri));
        fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
        bundle.putString("title", getString(R.string.contac));
        fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_privy) {
        bundle.putString("title", getString(R.string.privy_p));
        fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_advert) {
        bundle.putString("title", getString(R.string.advert));
        fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    } else if (id == R.id.spons) {
        bundle.putString("title", getString(R.string.spons));
        fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    } else if (id == R.id.app_about) {
        //fragment = new abtFragment();
    } else if (id == R.id.settings) {
        //fragment = new SettingFragment;
    }



    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "visible_fragment");
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.commit();

    //setTitle(item.getTitle()); // No longer needed.

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

In `onCreateView` of the fragment I received the String thus:

```
String title = getArguments().getString("title");
```

And then still in `onCreateView` I did:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
```

And the title is getting updated now.

The only problem that's is remaining now is the Navigation drawer item that refused to get updated.

And also Android Studio is complaining that *method invocation ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title); mayproduce java.lang.NullPointerException*.

Comment: In your stack the previous fragment is there so it only poping up the fragment on the back fragment , for the update you need to replace the container again on the backpress

Comment: @amit-ranjan: How Can I do that?

Comment: you have to replace the fragment

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **`Title`** for each `Fragment Transaction`.

Try by Changing on your `onNavigationItemSelected` like this.

```
Fragment fragment = null;
String title = "Test";

if (id == R.id.menu_home) {
    fragment = new PostFragment();
    title = "Post";
}

if (id == R.id.about_blog) {
    fragment = new PageFragment();
    title = "Page";
} else if (id == R.id.nav_contri) {
    fragment = new PageFragment();
    title = "Page";
} else if (id == R.id.nav_contact) {
    fragment = new PageFragment();
    title = "Page";
} else if (id == R.id.nav_privy) {
    fragment = new PageFragment();
    title = "Page";
} else if (id == R.id.nav_advert) {
    fragment = new PageFragment();
    title = "Page";
} else if (id == R.id.spons) {
    fragment = new PageFragment();
    title = "Page";
} else if (id == R.id.app_about) {
    //fragment = new abtFragment();
} else if (id == R.id.settings) {
    //fragment = new SettingFragment;
}

if (fragment != null) {
   FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
   ft.addToBackStack(null);
   ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
   ft.commit();

   **// set the toolbar title
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);**
}

DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
return true;
```

**EDIT 1:**

`OverRide onResume of your MainActivity`.

**Using this Code.**

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set title
    getActivity().getActionBar()
        .setTitle("Your Title Goes Here");
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, the title is set quite alright, but as before when I press back button, the title still takes that of the popped off fragment

Comment: @Ozuf Are you talking about `ActionBar Back Button` or System Back Button Press?

Comment: @Ozuf Have you override onBakcPressed in your Fragment class?

Comment: No, Sir I haven't.

Comment: @Ozuf Tell me 1 thing your `MainActivity Title` is Fixed always it is not Dynamic Right ? While Fragment have Dynamic Titles.

Comment: Yes, MainActivity has fixed title while fragment has dynamic titles.

Comment: @Ozuf Check my `EDIT 1` part of Answer. Let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the title of the current fragment?

Comment: @Ozuf I didn't get you  for this  how do I get the title of the current fragment? is it worked when you replaced fragment and on system back press activity title set correctly not previous ?

Comment: If I do `.setTitle("Home");` then the title of every fragment should become "Home", right?

Comment: Yes as in your if conditions fragment will take a title when you replace any `Fragment`.

Comment: When you are replacing fragment above code will be same no need to change `.setTitle("Home")`. make it as only `title = "Home"` like in above if consitions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110908/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-ozuf).

Comment: @Ozuf you mean when you press back button then again if you go to fragment titles are not changing right ?

Comment: If I select the fragments from the navigation drawer,  the title  of the fragments changes accordingly. But if for example in fragment "About", I  press back button to go to the previous fragment (say "Contract"), the title of fragment (Contract) is still that of fragment "About"

Comment: @Ozuf  Do same thing in each Fragment also like `overRide onResume method and` Pass your Title their.

Comment: Read my code again; I'm using the same fragment several times.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this.

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
         getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.titlefragment));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't make any difference. And the title should be dynamic since I'm using the same same fragment.

Comment: @Ozuf..you can also try like this...may it help you

Comment: How do I initialize  `title`?

Comment: I'm using the same fragment several times, this might work if I'm using different fragment each time.